# Gnuplot: Associating line and point color of a dataset to a colorbar

Tags: plot, gnuplot, colorbar

Consider the following minimal gnuplot script:

```
set terminal epslatex size 4.1,3
set out 'Plot.tex'

plot './Plot1.out' u 1:3 notitle w linespoints lt 1 pt 6 ps 1 lc rgb 'black', \
     './Plot2.out' u 1:3 notitle w linespoints lt 1 pt 6 ps 1 lc rgb 'red', \
     './Plot3.out' u 1:3 notitle w linespoints lt 1 pt 6 ps 1 lc rgb 'blue', \
     './Plot4.out' u 1:3 notitle w linespoints lt 1 pt 6 ps 1 lc rgb 'green'

set out
```

I currently plot each plot with colors black, red, blue, and green for plots 1, 2, 3, and 4, respectively. How can I add a colorbar associated to the range [1,4], and have the colors of each plot correspond to their associated plot number (1, 2, 3, or 4)?

**Edit**: I specifically do not want to use a key for this purpose because in my actual example, I have 3 subplots stacked side-by-side, and 8 datasets in each (8 keys in each subplot makes the plot look really cluttered). Therefore, I would like to have a single colorbar that is common to all 3 subplots indicating the number of the dataset (1, 2, 3, etc.) in each subplot. See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP19A.jpg) taken from [this journal article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2590055220300123) for an example of what I mean.

Comment: sorry, no access to the link...

Comment: I will upload a screenshot in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not fully clear to me what you mean with colorbar?
Do you mean the legend or key?
With `notitle` in the plot command you avoid having a key or legend.

Check the following minimal example:

**Code:**

```
### plots in a loop with key
reset session

set style line 1 pt 6 ps 1 lc rgb "black"
set style line 2 pt 6 ps 1 lc rgb "red"
set style line 3 pt 6 ps 1 lc rgb "blue"
set style line 4 pt 6 ps 1 lc rgb "green"

set key top center

plot for [i=1:4] '+' u 1:($1*i) w lp ls i title sprintf("%d",i)

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

For your specific files add a function which defines your filenames and exchange the plot command accordingly.

```
myFile(i) = sprintf("./Plot%d.out",i)

plot for [i=1:4] myFile(i) u 1:3 w lp ls i title sprintf("%d",i)
```

**Addition:**

Then maybe something like this? This just shows the principle. Arranging the multiplot in a nice way with equal graph size and distances to each other and the colorbox is another topic.

**Code:**

```
### plots in a loop without key but colorbox
reset session

set style line 1 pt 6 ps 1
set style line 2 pt 6 ps 1
set style line 3 pt 6 ps 1
set style line 4 pt 6 ps 1

set palette defined (1 "black", 2 "red", 3 "blue", 4 "green")

set multiplot layout 2,2

    set cbtics 1
    set key out top right
    unset colorbox
    plot for [i=1:4] '+' u 1:($1*i):(i) w lp pt 6 palette notitle

    unset ytics
    set colorbox
    plot for [i=1:4] '+' u 1:($1*i):(i) w lp pt 6 palette notitle

    unset colorbox
    set ytics
    plot for [i=1:4] '+' u 1:($1*i):(i) w lp pt 6 palette notitle

    unset ytics
    set colorbox
    set palette maxcolors 4
    plot for [i=1:4] '+' u 1:($1*i):(i) w lp pt 6 palette notitle

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I specifically put 'notitle' because I don't want to have to include a key. This is because in my actual plot, there are 8 plots. And I want to use multiplot to have 3 separate subplots with the same y-axes stacked side by side. So I would like to add a single vertical bar specifying the color (colorbar) on the right side of the multiplot so that I don't have to set a key in each subplot. I hope I've clarified things? (I suspect the correct gnuplot term is colormap, but I'm not too sure)

Comment: Thanks so much! The addition to your original answer is exactly what I'm looking for :)